# Can I fix a background on a phone relative to the screen? (note: not window)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css

I would like the background of a web page on a phone to not shift when the menu bars appear and disappear. I've set the background to `position: fixed; bottom: 0`. This keeps it fixed in the Chrome browser, since there is no toolbar or other menus on the bottom, and lessens the shifting in iOS and Android native browser, since the bottom toolbar is smaller than the top address bar. However, I would like to take this the next step further.

Is there a way to determine the element's position relative to the screen (not window) in order to determine the height of the top or bottom address bar, or any other built in means of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to get the screen height or width and use those values to style your element.

```
<script>
     var height = "Total Height: " + screen.height;
     var width = "Total Width: " + screen.width;
</script>
```

Comment: This will give you the screen dimensions, but it will tell you nothing about the position of the window relative to the screen. How many pixels from the top is the address bar pushing down the window, and how many pixels up from the bottom is the toolbar pushing it up?